# How do I avoid a race condition with Node.js's process.send?

Tags: node.js

What exactly happens when a child process (created by `child_process.fork()`) in Node sends a message to its parent (`process.send()`) before the parent has an event handler  for the message (`child.on("message",...)`)? (It seems, at least, like there must be *some kind* of buffer.)

In particular, I'm faced with what seems like an unavoidable race condition - I cannot install a message handler on a child process until after I've finished the call to `fork`, but the child could potentially send me (the parent) a message right away. What guarantee do I have that, assuming a particularly horrible interleaving of OS processes, I will receive *all* messages sent by my child?

Consider the following example code:

parent.js:

```js
const child_process = require("child_process");
const child_module = require.resolve("./child");

const run = async () => {
  console.log("parent start");
  const child = child_process.fork(child_module);
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 40));
  console.log("add handler");
  child.on("message", (m) => console.log("parent receive:", m));
  console.log("parent end");
};

run();
```

child.js:

```js
console.log("child start");
process.send("123abc");
console.log("child end");
```

In the above, I'm hoping to simulate a "bad interleaving" by preventing the message handler from being installed for a few milliseconds (suppose that a context switch takes place immediately after the fork, and that some other processes run for a while before the parent's node.js process can be scheduled again). In my own testing, the parent seems to "reliably" receive the message with numbers << 40ms (e.g. 20ms), but for values >35ms, it's flaky at best, and for values >> 40ms (e.g. 50 or 60), the message is never received. What's special about these numbers - just how fast the processes are being scheduled on my machine?

It seems to be independent of whether the handler is installed before or after the message is sent. For example, I've observed both of the following executions with the timeout set to 40 milliseconds. Notice that in each one, the child's "end" message (indicating that the process.send() has already happened) comes before "add handler". In one case, the message is received, but in the next, it's lost. It's possible, I suppose, that buffering of the standard output of these processes could potentially cause these outputs to be misrepresenting the true execution - is that's what's going on here?

```
Execution A:
  parent start
  child start
  child end
  add handler
  parent end
  parent receive: 123abc
```

```
Execution B:
  parent start
  child start
  child end
  add handler
  parent end
```

In short - is there a solution to this apparent race condition? I seem to be able to "reliably" receive messages as long as I install a handler "soon" enough - but am I just getting lucky, or is there some guarantee that I'm getting? How do I ensure, without relying on luck, that this code will *always* work (barring cosmic rays, spilled coffee, etc...)? I can't seem to find any detail about how this is supposed to work in the Node documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly happens when a child process (created by child_process.fork()) in Node sends a message to its parent (process.send()) before the parent has an event handler for the message (child.on("message",...))? (It seems, at least, like there must be some kind of buffer.)

First off, the fact that a message arrived from another process goes into the nodejs event queue.  It won't be processed until the current nodejs code finishes whatever it was doing and returns control back to the event loop so that it can process the next event in the event queue.  If that moment arrives before there is any listener for that incoming event, then it is just received and then thrown away.  The message arrives, the code looks to call any registered event handlers and if there are none, then it's done.  It's the same as if you call `eventEmitter.emit("someMsg", data)` and there are no listeners for `"someMsg"`.  But, read on, there is hope for your specific situation.

> In particular, I'm faced with what seems like an unavoidable race condition - I cannot install a message handler on a child process until after I've finished the call to fork, but the child could potentially send me (the parent) a message right away. What guarantee do I have that, assuming a particularly horrible interleaving of OS processes, I will receive all messages sent by my child?

Fortunately, due to the single-threaded, event-driven nature of nodejs, this is not a problem.  You can install the message handler before there's any chance of the message arriving and being processed.  This is because even though the child may be started up and may be running independently using other CPUs or interleaved with your process, the single-threaded nature and the event driven architecture help you solve this problem.

If you do something like this:

```
const child = child_process.fork(child_module);
child.on("message", (m) => console.log("parent receive:", m));
```

Then you are guaranteed that your message handler will be installed before there's any chance of an incoming message being processed and you will not miss it.  This is because the interpreter is busy running these two lines of code and does not return control back to the event loop until after these two lines of code are run.  Therefore, no incoming message from the child_module can get processed before your `child.on(...)` handler is installed.

---

Now, if you purposely do return back to the event loop as you are doing here with the `await` before installing your event handler like your code here:

```
const run = async () => {
  console.log("parent start");

  const child = child_process.fork(child_module);

  // this await allows events in the event queue to be processed
  // while this function is suspended waiting for the await
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 40));

  console.log("add handler");
  child.on("message", (m) => console.log("parent receive:", m));
  console.log("parent end");
};

run();
```

Then, you have purposely introduced a race condition with your own coding that can be avoided by just installing the event handler BEFORE the `await` like this:

```
const run = async () => {
  console.log("parent start");

  // no events will be processed before these next three statements run
  const child = child_process.fork(child_module);
  console.log("add handler");
  child.on("message", (m) => console.log("parent receive:", m));

  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 40));

  console.log("parent end");
};

run();
```

Comment: I see - so my race condition is a symptom of the particular way I chose to slow down my parent - the await handed control back to the event loop, which then had a chance to receive and throw away the message. If I had instead chosen to spin-wait with a while loop (or something similar), then I'd have no issue. Is that accurate?

Comment: @AndrewGies - That's correct, though I would never, ever recommend a spin-wait in nodejs, other than as some sort of temporal test case.